# javascript function format which allow to be accessed from the same javascript file and HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need following javascript code add into a function. But this function should be able to call from both same JavaScript file and relative HTML code file.

```
Profile.query(function(result) { 
    SchedulesByInterviewer(result["userName"]); 
});
```

When I write the function in below format, it is ok to access it from HTML by calling `vm.laodschedules();` but cannot be accessed from the JavaScript code.

```
vm.laodschedules = function(){
    Profile.query(function(result) { 
         SchedulesByInterviewer(result["userName"]);
    });
}
```

Then if I use below format it is ok to access the function from JavaScript code by calling `laodschedules()` but it cannot be accessed from HTML code.

```
function laodschedules() {
    Profile.query(function(result) { 
        SchedulesByInterviewer(result["userName"]);
    });
}
```

How can I manage to write this function enabling access from both JavaScript code and relevant HTML code?

Comment: Javascript code? you mean the controller file?

Comment: `vm.laodschedules();` this can work if you are calling from controller. Make sure you are calling function after declaration `vm.laodschedules = function(){...}`. Please share your controller code..

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 var laodschedules = function(){
        Profile.query(function(result) { 
             SchedulesByInterviewer(result["userName"]);
        })
    }

vm.laodschedules = laodschedules;
```

Now,

Call in controller (js) -    `laodschedules()`

Call in view (html)- `vm.laodschedules()`